# Можно ли через firebase сделать полную двухфакторную регистрацию для android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

Необходимо сделать регистрацию и после обращаться к базе данных firebase. Все вроде понятно, но клиент хочет полную 2-хфакторную регистрацию:

> "1 этап: логин и пароль 2 этап: если логин и пароль подходит, то
> приложение запрашивает подтверждение: нужно ввести номер телефона,
> чтобы пришла смс с кодом подтверждения "

Я почитал документацию и в файрбейс это все как то отдельно. Или регистрация по емейлу паролю или регистрация тупо по телефону с смс. А вот все вместе как то не нашел. А если пользователь незарегестрирован то доступ к бд запрещен и когда пользователь логинится в приложение, получается ему надо все равно сразу телефон вводить, а надо как вверху и получается, что к бд чтобы просто посмотреть есть ли там вообще этот юзер, не имею доступ потому что юзер не авторизирован.
Я конечно сделаю с помощью отдельного сервера такое, но это как то перебор. Мне кажется такое возможно просто не знаю как.

Comment: Вам регистрацию или все-таки MFA: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/multi-factor

Comment: Спасибо невнимательный был пропустил. Ну как бы как клиент написал.  Надо будет почитать тяжелое что то, вообще уже почти начал делать через сервер логин пароль, но теперь наверено еще подумаю как лучше.